# Display tag without getters and setters

Tags: displaytag

I want to know whether it is possible to use display tag without getters and setters.
The columns cannot be predictable one here because the query will return any column.In this case how we can perform with display tag

Answer (score 0):

In a Java class access to the properties/fields  can be controlled by access modifier.Now Display Tag have a very useful purpose and so many thing to do, If you give it the pressure of thinking how to access the properties it will be a little illogical. That's why not only `Display tag` many others library and framework use setter getter   to access properties and it is conventional to follow this approach.

Finally you can't access java properties without setter getters .